# Repeating code when sorting information from a txt-file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat

I'm having some problem with avoiding my code to repeat itself, like the title says, when I import data from a txt-file. My question is, if there is a smarter way to loop the function. I'm still very new to python in general so I don't have good knowledge in this area.

The code that I'm using is the following

```
with open("fundamenta.txt") as fundamenta:
    fundamenta_list = []
    for row in fundamenta:
        info_1 = row.strip()
        fundamenta_list.append(info_1)

namerow_1 = fundamenta_list[1]
sol_1 = fundamenta_list[2]
pe_1 = fundamenta_list[3]
ps_1 = fundamenta_list[4]
namerow_2 = fundamenta_list[5]
sol_2 = fundamenta_list[6]
pe_2 = fundamenta_list[7]
ps_2 = fundamenta_list[8]
namerow_3 = fundamenta_list[9]
sol_3 = fundamenta_list[10]
pe_3 = fundamenta_list[11]
ps_3 = fundamenta_list[12]
```

So when the code is reading from "fundamenta_list" how do I change to prevent code repetition?

Comment: Why you have to insert all that information to those variables? You can access the data straight from 'fundamenta_list'.

Comment: I'm creating objects from the variables. at the time the number of these are 3, but in the future the list can grow larger thus making me think that a more standardized approach is needed!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "My question is, if there is a smarter way to loop the function". There is no any function in your sample code. Did my answer below help you?

Comment: And why do you have insert data to variables? You can create objects like this: object = Object(fundamenta_list[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your input file has records each as a block of 4 rows, so in turn is `namerow`, `sol`, `pe`, `ps`, and you'll be creating objects that take these 4 fields. Assuming your object is called `MyObject`, you can do something like:

```
with open("test.data") as f:
    objects = []
    while f:
        try:
            (namerow, sol, pe, ps) = next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(), next(f).strip(), next(f).strip()
            objects.append(MyObject(namerow, sol, pe, ps))
        except:
            break
```

then you can access your objects as `objects[0]` etc.

You could even make it into a function returning the list of objects like in Moyote's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you may want to make a function out of your code, so you can avoid repeating the same code.

You can do this:

```
def read_file_and_save_to_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
    list_to_return = []
    for row in f:
        list_to_return.append(row.strip())
    return list_to_return
```

Then afterwards you can call the function like this:

```
fundamenta_list = read_file_and_save_to_list("fundamenta.txt")
```

Comment: This looks promising, and yes that is what i meant! Sorry if I was unclear. I will try this right away!

Comment: @Jurkka, did it help?

Comment: The thing I wanted to improve with the code was the variables such as "namerow_1"... etc. so the code can read an infinitely long txt-file and create objects following the same pattern. So i guess some kind of loop is needed to fix that, and that is the bigger problem im having. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @Jurkka, but I still don't understand why do you want to store that data to variables, since it is already stored in the list.